# Does the curve $2^2 x^2 + 4^2 y^2 = (x^2 + y^2)^2$ pass through $(0,0)$?

Tags: graphing-functions, curves

Any ideas about why Desmos/[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+2%5E2+x%5E2+%2B+4%5E2+y%5E2+%3D+(x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2)%5E2)) does not show $(0,0)$ as a part of the curve $$2^2 x^2 + 4^2 y^2 = (x^2 + y^2)^2$$ will be appreciated.

Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing coordinates

$$
x = r\cos\theta\\
y=r\sin\theta
$$

we get

$$
r^2 (r^2 + 6 \cos(2\theta)-10) =0
$$

so clearly appear the two solutions

$$
r = 0\\
r^2 + 6 \cos(2\theta)-10=0
$$

[image]

Comment: This answer should be upvoted

Answer (score 5):

Not, it's not a bug. Yes, $(0,0)$ belongs to that curve, but it is an isolated point of the curve. In other words, no nearby point belongs to the curve. That's why you can't see it.